# How to stop the SelectionChanged event after the datgrid is populated?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a Silverlight datagrid that will change its data source dynamically at runtime, and the datagrid has a SelectionChanged event handler. But I don't want the SelectionChanged event handler to be fired every time the data source is changed. Is there a easy way to prevent this happening?

Thanks,

Wei

Comment: I think I figured it out. Just unload (-=) the selection changed event handler before change the datasource, and add it back(+=) in the datagrid loaded event. Let me know if I am wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly unload (-=) the event handler and then load it back (+=) after you change the datasource.  That should work fine.  I would like to offer a suggestion, however.  Instead of wiring up the SelectionChanged, does the Silverlight DataGrid have a SelectedItem property that you can bind to instead?  If so, then you can bind that to a property in a class and listen for PropertyChanged on that property.  Then you can lose the event handler entirely.  That sets you up better for unit testing and is more in line with an MVVM philosophy.